# How to read the table variable from a backing bean in JSF?

Tags: jsf, trinidad

I am using MyFaces Trinidad, and want to create a single page where selection in one table reloads the content of another table to match the selection.

The update is triggered by an `actionListener` in a `partialSubmit`. Then I wanted the listener in the backing bean to remember the row object of the submit, such that the getter for the value of the second table can use this as a filter.

The Trinidad documentation includes this sample, but this syntax is deprecated in JSF 1.2:

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
MyClass selection = (MyClass)context.getVariableResolver().
    resolveVariable(context, "rowdata");
```

Anybody got a good suggestion?

Comment: Do you have a link to the example you're quoting from?

Answer (score 1):

The JSF 1.2 way is using ELResolver. Also see the deprecation notes in the javadoc of VariableResolver. A more common JSF 1.2 alternative is the Application#evaluateExpressionGet(). Code examples can be found [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/communication-in-jsf.html#AccessingAnotherManagedBean).

Answer (score 0):

You may find this post helpful: http://ocpsoft.com/java/jsf-java/jsfs-hdatatable-vs-uirepeat-how-to-get-the-selected-row/